# Java Multithreaded server not working

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

So I'm trying to create a Server/Client in Java to improve my skills. But.. For some reason, though I create a new thread each time the server accepts a connection, things just don't work and only one client is working.
Here''s the code:

```
  while (true) {
            Socket client = null;
            client = server.accept();
            new Thread(new Server(client)).run();
        }
```

And I have no idea why it's happening. I use a tutorial for this and yet, things don't work.
Thanks!

Comment: What tutorial? Show your sources.

Comment: Instead of run there must be start and you need to define the run method.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the solution for the problem.

> "So what is difference between start and run method? Main difference
>   is that when program calls start() method a new Thread is created and
>   code inside run() method is executed in new Thread while if you call
>   run() method directly no new Thread is created and code inside run()
>   will execute on current Thread.
>   Quoted from http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/difference-between-start-and-run-method.html

Changing the .run() function to .start() solved the problem.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

[Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) is a very good Java library which provides a clean and simple API for efficient TCP and UDP client/server network communication using NIO.

It will make your network programming work a lot more easier, and you can get a better understanding of how to write client and server side code.

I would suggest that you try out your network programming skills using this library first and then try implementing your own.